# makefile using g++ -c and g++ -fopenmp

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, openmp

I've defined an object within `mathobj.cpp` and its methods in `sum1.cpp` and `multiple.cpp`. The code in this methods uses the [openmp](http://openmp.org/wp/) library

What would be the equivalent makefile to the following compilation commands:

```
g++ -c main.cpp mathobj.cpp -fopenmp sum1.cpp multiple.cpp
g++ -fopenmp main.o mathobj.o sum1.o multiple.o -o Test
```

Comment: This isn't clear. You could put that directly into a makefile recipe if you so chose.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the below Makefile:

Makefile:

```
SRCS = main.cpp \
        mathobj.cpp \
        sum.cpp \
        multiple.cpp

OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o )

.PHONY: all clean

all: test
test : $(OBJS)
[TAB] g++ -fopenmp $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp 
[TAB] g++ -fopenmp -c $< -o $@

clean:
[TAB] rm -rf *.o test
```

Comment: This is the output of compilation:  g++ -fopenmp  -o test
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [test] Error 4

Comment: Each rule has be tab spaced from the start. Problem with how you copied the makefile.

Answer (score 2):

I think most people write `Makefile`s which are way too long.

Your task gets much easier if you rename your `main.cpp` to `Test.cpp`. Then you don't have to define any rules in your Makefile but you can use the implicit rules.

After the rename, the `Makefile` gets really simple:

```
CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
Test: mathobj.o sum.o multiple.o
```

That's all you need!

```
$ make
g++ -fopenmp   -c -o mathobj.o mathobj.cpp
g++ -fopenmp   -c -o sum.o sum.cpp
g++ -fopenmp   -c -o multiple.o multiple.cpp
g++ -fopenmp    Test.cpp mathobj.o sum.o multiple.o   -o Test
```

But, if you want, you can also skip the intermediate step and compile everything in one go (again, those 2 lines are all you need in your `Makefile`):

```
CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
Test: mathobj.cpp sum.cpp multiple.cpp
```

This leads to:

```
$ make
g++ -fopenmp    Test.cpp mathobj.cpp sum.cpp multiple.cpp   -o Test
```